# Where can I find a minimal spring boot boilerplate web app with backend and frontend?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-applications

I want a barebone template project for a webapp implemented using *spring boot* (frontend + backend APIs - DB)

I referred this [VS Code's doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-webapp) for working with Java. It worked fine but it is not a complete webapp.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) is a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) framework for web apps driven through [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot). (Alternatively, you can base your Vaadin app on [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) or plain [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet).)

A customized project template can be generated from their ["Start building" web page](https://vaadin.com/start).

You can manage your Vaadin project with either [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate an app with spring boot + angular/reactjs/vuejs I think that the best solution by far at this moment is JHipster.